# How to split huge list into small sublists separated by specific marks

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split

I have a text file "ss.txt" that looks like below when read by `readlines()`.

```
table=open("ss.txt", 'r')
lines=table.readlines()
lines

['> \n',
 '34.65244 126.76509\n',
 '34.68870 126.76670\n',
 '34.68874 126.76928\n',
 '> \n',
 '35.20824 127.59218\n',
 '35.23883 127.61384\n',
 '35.25724 127.63202\n',
 '35.28176 127.65381\n',
 '35.32153 127.68277\n',
 '35.35514 127.70445\n',
 '35.38568 127.72249\n',
 '35.41014 127.74064\n',
 '35.42854 127.75889\n',
 '> \n',
 '38.92037 125.18419\n',
 '38.93961 125.19820\n',
 '38.95427 125.21546\n',
 '38.96442 125.23898\n',
 '38.97476 125.26852\n',
 '> \n',
 '38.96688 125.70819\n',
 '38.95062 125.71496\n',
 '38.92977 125.72494\n',
 '38.90664 125.73803\n',
 '> \n',
 '38.94162 125.64620\n',
 '38.94397 125.64609\n',
 '38.94405 125.64909\n',
 '38.95638 125.66957\n',
 '38.96385 125.68426\n']
```

What I want to do is get rid of `'> \n'` and split the list into a list of sublists that looks like

```
[[[34.65244, 126.76509], [34.68870, 126.76670], [34.68874, 126.76928]], [[35.20824, 127.59128], [35.23883, 127.61384], [35.25724, 127.63202], ...], ...].
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in Python language?

Comment: Please edit question and post the data as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), like this:

```
l = [l.split() for l in lst if not l.startswith('>')]
```

This will filter out any line that starts with `>`, keeping only the lines with numbers. The use of [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) will split the line into a list of numbers.

If you want to convert those numbers into `float`s that can be subsequently used more easily, you can incorporate another list comprehension, like this:

```
l = [[float(n) for n in l.split()] for l in lst if not l.startswith('>')]
```

**Edit:** it appears maybe your question is asking for sub-arrays for each segment of the list separated by `>`. If this is the case, then the following would fit that requirement:

```
l = [r for r in [[[float(m) for m in n.split()] for n in l.split('\n')[:-1]] for l in ''.join(lst).split('> \n')] if r != []]
```

This is somewhat more convoluted. We first join the entire list and then split at occurrences of `> \n`, so we can form sub-arrays from that. The rest follows the approach taken above, but we have to remove the extra "empty" elements that result from the split -- hence the outer list comprehension and the use of the negative slice `[:-1]`.

Comment: s/lst/lines/ also looking closely at the expected result he wants a sub-array for each chunk that is separated by \n

Comment: Quite possibly, though the answer was accepted already, so maybe that wasn't the intention?

Comment: I've updated to include a method for the sub-array interpretation of the question (albeit somewhat convoluted), if that's what the OP actually wanted instead.

Comment: Actually your edit was what I desired but I figured out with help of your ordinary answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Define a generator that creates the sublists for each separator ('> \n'), and don't return empty lists (i.e. the initial \n):

```
def group(lines, sep):
  g = []
  for l in lines:
    if l == sep:
      if g:
        yield g
        g = []
    else:
      g.append(l)
  yield g
```

Then iterate over each group (g) and split line (l) then convert each field (f) to a float:

```
[ [ map(lambda f: float(f), l.split()) for l in g ] for g in group(lines, '> \n') ]
```

(I tried to use a list comprehension instead of a map() but I would get an error about l being undefined).

Comment: Fixed as suggested.

Comment: Reworked solution to answer question unlike my first attempt.